# Diskless Ubuntu client - UFW enable hangs system

Tags: networking, server, firewall, ufw, nfs

I have successfully created diskless Ubuntu system instance via [this community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto) and it works perfectly. However, I would like to enable firewall with UFW and when I tried to do that the problem appeared.

As part of the tutorial on help page I prepared complete "filesystem" with other installation and already bootstraped OS with my settings there (installed necessary packages, changed configs, ...). Later on I copied it to NFS directory and booted it via diskless machine. Everything was successfully loading (printing out OK status when  started each service to console) until the moment when a loader with unlimited start time was shown. One of the starting services was also UFW. At some point system became unresponsive (I could still move the console with Shift-Pg Up/Down, but nothing was actually happening there). I could not get around that until I figured out UFW is the main problem causing this. So I disabled UFW in `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` (directly on NFS server) and retry with booting. At that time everything went well and system was successfully booted up.

But still I would like to have UFW enabled, so I tried to do that directly from the machine. And there the same problem reappeared. Soon as I executed `ufw enable` system became unresponsive. I have captured output from dmesg when this command executes:

```
[ xxxx.xxxxxx ] bpfilter: Loaded bpfilter_umh pid 748
[ xxxx.xxxxxx ] Started filter
```

And then system was unresponsive for 2 minutes, when I got another few messages:

```
[ xxxx.xxxxxx ] INFO: task systemd-journal:278 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[ xxxx.xxxxxx ]       Not tainted 5.4.0-86-generic #97-Ubuntu
[ xxxx.xxxxxx ] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

I thought there may be problem with default rules disallowing NFS connection. So I added next rules (step by step and tried to enable UFW after each):

```
ufw allow from 192.168.0.5    # NFS server
ufw allow from 192.168.0.0/24 # local network
ufw allow in on eth0          # client network interface
```

But no luck with this (also I was not expecting it, as those rules should not have any impact by logic).

So here I am now, without any idea at the moment how to do any progress on this. I can also point out there is another problem in dmesg, but it probably does not have any relation to the one with UFW:

```
[ xxx.xxxxxx] systemd-journald[276]: Failed to set ACL on /var/log/jorunal/.../user-101.journal, ignoring: Operation not permitted
```

I believe there must be some rule with UFW which by default denies access to NFS share and therefore complete system hangs up. Any suggestion/point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
iptables output when UFW is enabled and my rules are also added (copied from the original installation) is here: https://pastebin.com/rp5QWLCh

Comment: ufw is just a front end for iptables. edit your question with the output from `sudo iptables -xvnL`. While ufw generated iptables rule sets are difficult to follow, perhaps it will help.

Comment: @DougSmythies I have added link to pastebin where iptables output is pasted.

Comment: You mention "So I disabled UFW in /etc/ufw/ufw.conf (directly on NFS server)" Do I understand correctly that the iptables rule set you listed runs on the server and not on the diskless client? If yes, then I agree it will not work. If no, it runs on the diskless client, then I do not know why it is not working, looks O.K. to me.

Comment: The quoted text means that I powered off diskless client and then edited option `enabled = yes` to `enabled = no` in client's file `ufw.conf` directly from NFS server (NOT the file which is for NFS server itself, because the server does not have ufw at all, but I believe the server's firewall is correctly configured as everything works otherwise) ...

Comment: While I agree that it shouldn't make a difference, could you please post the `sudo iptables -xvnL` listing with `ufw allow from 192.168.0.5    # NFS server` added.

Comment: Try a higher log level, maybe `LOGLEVEL=high` in `/etc/ufw/ufw.conf` and post its contents.

Comment: Output from iptables with that specific rule: https://pastebin.com/dEVPKZDF I also changed `LOGLEVEL` (before diskless client boot), but after I tried to enable ufw on diskless client only `bpfilter` logs were added (two lines as in the post above) in `dmesg`. As expected system hanged then.

Comment: We don't want to go to log level "full", because it would flood your system. I have been trying to figure out why the "bpfilter_umh" module is loading in the first place. It doesn't on my system. I haven't figured out what to do to have it not load, even if just for a test. I can think of two tests to attempt to gain more insight: First, use UFW but allow everything, i.e. UFW is enabled but basically a no-op; Second , try a simple iptables script, to see if it works and if the "bpfilter_umh" module is still loaded.

Comment: describe your client computer hardware. Processor make and model, NIC etc. I had a problem earlier this year, where my hardware was too new for the 5.4 series kernels. Depending on your hardware, and as a test, try a newer kernel, say [mainline ppa 5.15-rc3](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.15-rc3/) (it seems there was a compile problem with 5.15-rc4).

Comment: On multiple computers, I have tried basic ufw and iptables rule sets and the bpfilter_umh module is never loaded.

Comment: Can you check/share: **ufw status numbered**

Comment: @DougSmythies it is not problem with specific hardware - it can be KVM or custom built machine on Intel 775 socket or HP DC7800 SFF (this is what I tested with so far and I don't believe it could be a hardware related problem). I will try with different kernel anyway and let you know. Originally I used Ubuntu minimal cloud img in VM and then converted it to generic kernel and removed cloud-init/netplan related stuff - it could also be that this affected system somehow.